# Mysql Update with table joins - update one table's field with sum of other table's field

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables `Orders` and `Order_Details`
`Order_Details` tables's `order_id` field acts as foreign key to `Orders` table's `id_order` table.

I want to update the `price_total` field of `Orders` table with summation of prices from `Order_Details` table.

I tried with the following query but failed:-

```
Update Orders, Order_Details
  SET  Orders.price_total = sum(Order_Details.price)
 WHERE Orders.price_total=0
 GROUP BY Order_Details.id_order
```

Error -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY Order_Details.id_order' at line 4
```

How to do it in one query?

Thanks

Comment: you did not speciy which column in Orders link to Order_Details.id_order

Comment: @ajreal - `Order_Details` tables's `order_id` field acts as foreign key to `Orders` table's `id_order` table. Applied correction in queation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify it to

```
Update Orders 
SET Orders.price_total = 
(
  SELECT 
    sum(Order_Details.price) 
  FROM Order_Details 
  WHERE 
    Orders.id_order=Order_Details.order_id
)
WHERE Orders.price_total=0;
```

<strike>**updated** for grouping</strike>

```
Update Orders, Order_Details
  SET Orders.price_total = sum(Order_Details.price)
WHERE 
  Orders.price_total=0 AND
  Orders.id_order=Order_Details.order_id    
GROUP BY Order_Details.id_order
```

Comment: Thanks I was struggling with the subquery method too today. :)  Anyway please answer if you could correct the joining and grouping method too.

Comment: Still getting the same error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY Order_Details.id_order' at line 6`

Comment: @sandeepan - group by cannot use with update, sorry for the wrong information