# Update Table with sum based on column value

Tags: mysql

I would like to sum the values of a column, based on another columns value. My table looks like this:

```
|----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
|         col1         |       col2        |      result    |
|----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
|          a           |        5          |       12       |
|          a           |        7          |       12       |
|          b           |        9          |       209      |
|          b           |        200        |       209      |
|          c           |        56         |       56       |
|----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
```

The result column is the anticipated result. So the sum of the values in col2 for a in col1 would be 12 for every row that has col1=a. I want to do this with an update and set statement

Here's what I have so far:

```
    UPDATE Result o 
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT col1, SUM(col2) sumcol
       FROM Result
       GROUP BY col1
    ) i ON o.col2 = i.col1
    SET o.result = i.sumcol
```

I'm having trouble finding the right way to do this. I'm mainly getting syntax errors. I've tried different variations of this query (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551364/mysql-update-with-select-sum-from-different-table)) but none has worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - but equally, consider whether you really want to store easily derived data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modified query:

```
UPDATE Result o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1, SUM(col2) AS sumcol
    FROM Result
    GROUP BY col1
) i ON o.col1 = i.col1
SET o.result = i.sumcol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the query below :

```
UPDATE Result o1 SET o1.result = (
     SELECT SUM(o2.col2) sumcol
     FROM Result o2
     GROUP BY o2.col1
     WHERE o2.col1 = o1.col1
)
```

EDIT : Jocelyn answer is the one, you probably joined on the wrong column and i didn't see it.